# Store Structure with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am currently trying to understand how react and redux works. I cloned this [repo](https://github.com/dceddia/redux-intro) and checked with chrome developer tools how it looks like. The store is structured like that: "$r.store". If I generate a project with create-react-app and copy the code of the repository my store is structured differently. It looks like this: "$r.state.store" Is there any mistake I do? Am I doing something essentially wrong?

Answer (score 0):

***$r* is just a reference for a selected element in RDT (React Developers Tools)**

So depending on the element you select above, you'll be able to see one thing or the other.

For viewing the actual structure of your state you'll normally need to call: `$r.state.store.getState()`

I recommend you to use [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) Chrome plugin to see the state in a better way.

Here are the steps you need to follow to make everything working: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#11-basic-store